# How to convert a servlet request to a JSON request

Tags: json, web-services, servlets, postman, restlet

I had an application that is running with servelets. I want to test that application using REST services or POSTMAN.

So, I want to know, whether it could be possible to convert a servelet application's request and response into JSON for testing it with Postman or REST services.

If this possible, how do I do this conversion?

Comment: You cant convert it for testing no. You can convert it to REST completely.

Comment: can you explain in deep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some context would be helpful. What does the request to your application look like?

You don't need to convert an application's request / response into JSON to use postman. Postman is pretty flexible, you can send a variety of request content types to your application.

As far as whether or not this is possible, absolutely. If you want to convert your request & response objects to JSON, consider using something like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). You can use the ObjectMapper of this tool to go from JSON to POJO & vice versa